# Erasing pixel with .Net GDI+

Tags: .net, gdi+

How can I set the alpha channel of a pixel to zero using .Net GDI+ or API calls? 
How can I set to transparent a shaped area (for instance, having sort of an"Erasing" brush and using it with FillEllipse() or FillRectangle() methods) ?

Thank you.

Comment: An "erasing" brush? Do you intend to restore pixels to an earlier color using this "erasing" brush? That isn't possible. You will have to implement a technique similar to Photoshop layers. Filling with a transparent (alpha = zero) brush will have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a brush that's made from a Color that has an alpha of 0 (Color.FromArgb).  Since the RGB values don't really matter anymore, you might as well use Brushes.Transparent.  Make a single pixel transparent by drawing a rectangle of 1x1 with Graphics.FillRectangle().

Bitmap.MakeTransparent() is another way to quickly make an arbitrary background color transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy. Set the CompostingMode of the Graphics object to SourceCopy and use the Fill functions with a Brush created from a color with complete transparency(alpha component being 0).